# how to set focus for the pop-up window?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

In my web page I have opened a notification pop-up window which contains some message. My need is after opening that pop-up the focus should navigate in that particular window not in the main web.

I used the below codes to open the pop-up window

```
<div class="cd-popup">
        <div class="cd-popup-container">
            <asp:GridView runat="server"
                ID="gvNotificationsShow"
                                    AllowPaging="True"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                    GridLines="None"
                ShowHeader="true"
                class="tablemaster">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-CssClass="Grid">
                        <HeaderTemplate><span class="headerGradient">Notifications list</span></HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblNotification" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NotificationText").ToString().Replace("\n","<br/>") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:GridView>

            <a href="#" id="notify" onclick="openMarkup()" class="cd-popup-close">
                <img src="../Lib/UI/img/noimage.png" class="transparent" alt="no image"></a>
        </div>
        <!-- cd-popup-container -->
    </div>
```

Comment: is this webforms?

Comment: Can you post your JavaScript for `openMarkup` method?

Comment: I have these codes only for notification box '  <li id="notifybox"><a href="#" class="cd-popup-trigger" aria-haspopup="true" title="Notifications(Open a new PopUp)" >
                            <asp:Label ID="lblNotificationCount" runat="server"> </asp:Label>
                            <img src="../Lib/UI/img/icon-notification.png" alt="Notifications" />

                        </a>
                        </li>'

Comment: Are you having problems when you hit enter button??

Comment: No.... the requirement is when I open the PopUp, the focus should go to the PopUp and later, if  I push the keytab several times, the focus is out of the PopUp, the Focus  should not go outside while the PopUp is open.

Comment: basically you need to capture tab key and when popup is open you need to return false on keyup event of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided your JavaScript for `openMarkup` method, I will assume that you have a variable called `popupWindow` in that method.  Then, to move focus to the popup window, you could use JavaScript as below.

```
var popupWindow = window.open('xyz.aspx');//you could have more parameters passed to open method
if(window.focus) {
     popupWindow.focus();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this(requires Jquery)

```
$(document).on('keyup keypress', function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode === 9) {
    if($('#popupelementid').is(':visible'))
     {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
     }
    }
});
```